# Interfaces passing container of Interfaces

Tags: c++, oop, iterator

If there is an interface with a method signature as following,

```
class Interface2
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface2() {}
    virtual uint getId() = 0;
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
};

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface(){}
    virtual std::list<Interface2*> getData(uint id) = 0;
};
```

So basically the purpose of `getData(uint id)` is to expose the internal storage of `Interface2` interfaces

When implementing a concrete class `Interface`, it would keep the storage of objects made out of concrete classes of `Interface2`.

For example, following could be a way of implementing those interfaces

```
class Interface2Imp : public Interface2
{
public:
    uint getId() { return id;}
    std::string getName() { return name;}

private:
    uint id;
    std::string name;
};

class InterfaceImp : public Interface
{
public:
    std::list<Interface2*> getData(uint id)
    {
        std::list<Interface2*> returnList;
        std::list<Interface2Imp> & a = storage[id];
        for(auto & it : a)
        {
            returnList.push_back(&it);
        }
        return returnList;
    }

private:
    std::map<int, std::list<Interface2Imp> > storage;
}
```

But looking at how `getData(uint id)` is implemented we can see that it iterates over its internal storage and then again fill it out to a list of interfaces, which looks costly (and ugly).

Is there a better method to expose the internal data of an interfaces which happen to be exposed as interfaces as well?

Comment: Why not make `storage` a `std::map<int, std::list<std::unique_ptr<Interface2>>>` and then you can just return a reference to `storage[id]`?

Comment: But then the `InterfaceImp` would have to do operations on the contents of its storage as `Interface2` not as `Interface2Imp`. Or are you suggesting to cast it upwards to `Interface2Imp` when ever needed internally?

Answer (score 2):

as it stands the iterate and copy has to be done. The class stores a list of instances of X, you want a list of pointers to instances of X. These are 2 different things. You could maybe do some std::algorithm stuff etc but that does not change the fact that the iterate and clone must be done.

How about changing the interfaces and implementation. Make the class `InterfaceImp` store a List of shared_ptr to `Interface`, and make getData method return a List of shared_ptrs. Now the container can directly return its data. (Also you are not moving raw pointers around)

Having said that, what you have at the moment is a better encapsulation. You are not exposing your internal data to your caller, you are cloning it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is basically a `multimap<int, Interface2Imp>` but with a twist: outside users need to see `Interface2*` and not `Interface2Imp&`.

This is a model use case for *iterator adapters*. You can steal one from [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_adaptor.html#tutorial-example) or write your own. In the latter case you need a class that contains a real `multimap<int, Interface2Imp *>::const_iterator` member, forwards most iterator-y methods to it directly, and only adapts `operator *()` and `operator ->()` slightly differently (return what the internal member returns but upcasted to the base class pointer/reference).

If you don't want to mention `Interface2Imp` even in the private part of your iterator adapter, further hide it away with the Pimpl idiom.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to store smart pointers for the interface implementaion instances in 1st place:

```
class InterfaceImp : public Interface
{
public:
    const std::list<std::shared_ptr<Interface2>>& getData(uint id)
    {
        return storage[id];
    }

private:
    std::map<uint, std::list<std::shared_ptr<Interface2>> > storage;
}
```

If you need access to the `Interface2Imp` instances to access functions or data, that's not visible through `Interface2` you can always use a `static_cast<Interface2Imp*>` with those instances, because your `InterfaceImp` class knows what was used to instantiate the  `std::shared_ptr<Interface2>` implementations.
You can even do full runtime queries using `dynamic_cast<Interface2*>` if it is necessary and doesn't hit your application performance wise.